# Half arrow esvect

Tags: arrows

I use \vv{} from esvect for arrows above letters. I would like to make a half-arrow, with only half the ending arrow, similarly to \overrightharpoon ([image: Half arrow]) but that has a shape and length compatible with \vv ([image: Like this]).

I looked at the code for \vv but I do not understand it...

Note: I don't have to use esvect, I can use another package with nice looking arrows.

Comment: `MnSymbol` has `\overrightharpoon` and `\overleftharpoon`.

Comment: For the overrightharpoon H in your question, how did you get that straight arrowhead? I'm trying to get a straight arrowhead without changing the font and am finding myself slowly being driven to madness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metrics in `\hvec` are font dependent and the method likely has additional drawbacks.  For example, the horizontal kerning is not quite right on the `A` as can be seen.  But that said...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,trimclip,stackengine,scalerel}
\newsavebox\tmpbox
\newcommand\hvec[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}
  \setbox2=\hbox{$%
    \clipbox{0pt{} \dimexpr\ht0+1.68\LMpt{} -.2\LMpt{} 0pt}{%
      $\SavedStyle\mathaccent"017E{\phantom{\SavedStyle #1}}$}\kern-.2\LMpt$}
    \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{1.3\LMpt}{\SavedStyle#1}{\copy2}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}
}}
\begin{document}
$\vec A \vec a ^2 \scriptscriptstyle \vec A \sqrt{\vec a} $

$\hvec A \hvec a  ^2\scriptscriptstyle \hvec A \sqrt{\hvec a} $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the variant compatible with the `\vv` style.  Similar disclaimers apply:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,trimclip,stackengine,scalerel,esvect}
\newsavebox\tmpbox
\newcommand\hvv[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}
  \setbox2=\hbox{$%
    \clipbox{0pt{} \dimexpr\ht0+2.05\LMpt{} 0pt -1pt}{%
      $\SavedStyle\vv{\phantom{\SavedStyle #1}}$}$}
    \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{1.7\LMpt}{\SavedStyle#1}{\copy2}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}
}}
\begin{document}
$\vv A \vv a ^2 \scriptscriptstyle \vv A \sqrt{\vv a} $

$\hvv A \hvv a  ^2\scriptscriptstyle \hvv A \sqrt{\hvv a} $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer (I removed mathtools since it is apparently not needed and I do not have this package). I have this result, which looks strange though: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/414521hvv.png

Comment: @QuentinFortier The number that controls the vertical point of clipping is the `2.05\LMpt` (in the 1st example, `1.68\LMpt`).  You could try increasing the value to, for example, `2.10\LMpt`.